# Chrome 80 session cookie don't persist

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome

I know Chrome 80 has new cookie policy. Basically I have PHP script which is embeded on 3rd party websites as javascript file. That script creates a cookie for payment, redirects to stripe, then stripe goes back to redirect page, sets all necessary information in session and goes back to the initial site.

And now, if I literally grab that js url and open it in a browser then I have that session available, however when it is in `<script>` it looses that session. Everything worked fine until Chrome 80 and still works in other browsers. Here are headers of .php script that spits out javascript that is embeded:

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'None');
    session_set_cookie_params(['samesite' => 'None']);
    ob_start();
    $externalpage = true;
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    if($_REQUEST["sid"] != "") {
        $sid = $_REQUEST["sid"];
    }
    session_start();
```

and in my redirect file

```
<?php
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite', 'None');
session_set_cookie_params(['samesite' => 'None']);
session_id($_REQUEST["sid"]);
session_start();
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

Additionally I added `crossorigin="anonymous"` to `<script>`

Comment: have you read the documentation google published about changes to such cookies? published for developers last october - https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/developers-get-ready-for-new.html and another publication https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/samesite-cookie-changes-in-february.html

Comment: You are setting `SameSite=none`, but I don’t see you specifying the cookie as secure anywhere, which is also a requirement. Default value for `session.cookie_secure` is `off`.

Comment: I have added `session.cookie_secure` to `1` but that didn't help. PHP file that is the source of JavaScript is on local server so it is not `https` Does that matter?

Comment: Well secure means the cookie is to be send back only via HTTPS connections to begin with, so … yeah, obviously.

Comment: Unfortunatelly enabling SSL did not help at all. The script is working fine on Firefox. Now let's say my script is on source.com and it is embeded on any domain. What sould I put into headers? I have SameSite none secured to 1 but still nothing